# What is a "bound" function in a Solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle

When a deployed contract is shown in Truffle, some functions show up as

```
[Function: bound]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with Solidity. It's JavaScript.

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573071/what-does-function-bound-mean-when-node-debugging:

> `[Function: bound]` seems to be a bound function object, i.e. the result of a [`.bind()` call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this should be more clear to me but the contract is written in Solidity and the functions are names of Solidity functions; no prior experience with Javascript. Maybe Truffle documentation should clarify?

Comment: Truffle is a JavaScript framework, so you'll probably need to learn a bit about JavaScript to use it. I think it's reasonable for Truffle to assume some JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps it is clear what is happening from documentation.